# How to trigger a model update from another model in a collection in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

#### Update: Here is a working demo of the project I was working on: http://www.newedenfaces.com

I have two views: **PeopleView** that holds 2 thumbnails (collection) and **PersonView** - each thumbnail itself (model).

This is basically a Facemash clone where you have two images side-by-side. If one person wins the game, another one loses the game.

In order to update *wins count*, it's easy, just add this to the **PersonView**:

```
// Model View
events: {
    'click img': 'winner'
},
winner: function() {
    this.model.set('wins', this.model.get('wins') + 1);
    this.model.save();
}
```

But how do I update the other model by incrementing the *losses count?* Or should I be doing this type of logic at the collection level rather than on an individual model?

## Update

Until I find an elegant solution I've managed to solve this problem using this hack:

```
// Collection View
initialize: function() {
    this.collection.on('change:wins', this.updateLosses, this);
  },

  updateLosses: function(model) {
    var winnerIndex = this.collection.indexOf(model);
    var otherModel = this.collection.at(Math.abs(1 - winnerIndex));
    otherModel.set('losses', otherModel.get('losses') + 1);
    otherModel.save();
    this.render();
  },
```

My **PersonView** still handles the update of wins count. However the **PeopleView** collection view listens for the event when wins count is updated. When that happens it takes that model and gets its index position. Since I only have 2 views / 2 models, the other model must have been a "loser". You get the index of the other model via `Math.abs(1 - winnerIndex)`, and the only things that you have to do is update its *losses count*.

***Note***: I have just started learning Backbone, so this is my first project using it. **I really hope there is a better way to do this.** If you know, post an answer so I could accept and close this question.

Comment: By other model you meant the other thumbnail in PersonView?

Comment: Note: You don't need to pass attributes to save to the .save method - that's just a convenience if you haven't .set them already.

Comment: @nrabinowitz Thanks, I updated my code. For some reason I thought it would be more efficient that way, i.e. to send JSON with 1 attribute, rather than the entire model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to @pvnarula's answer, you can use Backbone's built in [Event](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) module
to create an event dispatcher that model views are bound to.

```
// Define an event dispatcher/handler
var dispatcher = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

// Model View
initialize: {
    this.listenTo(dispatcher, 'game:over', this.updateCounts);
}

events: {
    'click img': 'winner'
},

winner: function() {
    // just trigger the custom event and let each view figure out how to respond.
    // also pass along the id of the winning model
    dispatcher.trigger('game:over', this.model.id)
},

updateCounts: function(winnerId) {
    if (this.model.id === winnerId) {
        this.model.set('wins', this.model.get('wins') + 1); 
    } else {
        this.model.set('losses', this.model.get('losses') + 1);
    }
    this.model.save();
}
```

Also worth checking out this article for more about Backbone Events: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/03/revisiting-the-backbone-event-aggregator-lessons-learned/

Comment: Works great! One thing to note is that your method of defining a dispatcher did not work. I used this instead `var dispatcher = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);`

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer to use `_.extend` instead of `_.clone`

Comment: Jeff I am having a problem with updateCounts gets called more times than needed. First one time, then 2,4,6,8,10...while wins gets incremented by one. I now have 50,000 wins and over 190,000 losses as a result of this change. The only thing i am doing to the collection is shifting it twice (removing 2 elements) which I already had before this change.

Comment: It sounds like you are running into what are commonly called "zombie views" in Backbone (see http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/ )
You used to have to clean this up manually, but now Backbone has a better way of handling this using `listenTo` which I should have used in the original answer. I have updated my answer to use that  approach. You still need to make sure that you are cleaning up your child views properly by calling `remove` on them, but as long as you do that Backbone should take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I've heard of Backbone zombie views before, but didn't realize I'd stumble upon them so early in my Backbone experience.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you want to access other view from your current view and update it accordingly. I am afraid you need to create your own observer pattern. I mean publish and subscribe.

```
var otherView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize : function(){
       observer.subscribe('your_custom_event');
   },
   your_custom_event : function(){
      //update the view and it's model
   }
});

winner: function() {
    this.model.set('wins', this.model.get('wins') + 1);
    this.model.save({wins: this.model.get('wins')});
    observer.publish('your_custom_event', arguments);
}
```

You can get very good available patterns from the web easily those are compatible with backbone.

Comment: Hmm this looks like a good direction, but the thing is my thumbnail views are identical. I append them via addOne function similar to ToDo App. The only difference between thumbnail views is the model data they consume.

Comment: Yes, they both are different views and are attached to different models. So in order to build a link between them you need to take this way. The simple solution is to use backbone layoutManager module or backbone marionette layout module. These modules are very helpful for creating a layout for your views and you can get views and call there events very easily from other views. because everything is bind with other in the layout.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look into Marionette.